# Associating AJAX data with other AJAX data

Tags: javascript

I created my own challenge for the Javascript course I am taking by combining some concepts from past lectures from the course. I want to be able to choose one piece of data from a dropdown box and have a textbox fill with related data from the database. I am pulling the data using ajax. here is the page I have so far:

[image: page view]

The data is in a sql database and has been dumped to an 'ajax server' via PHP. I included it on the page for reference. As you can tell, i figured out how to populate the dropdown with the ajax data. here's the code I have so far:

```
const dataModule = (function(){

//some code

})();

const uiModule = (function(){

  const domStrings = {
    dropdown: '.dd',
  }

//get data from ajax
  const dropdown = document.querySelector('.dd');
  const getData = (async function() {
    const data = await (await fetch('http://localhost/Test2/ajaxservers/_family.php')).json();
    data.forEach(cur => {
      option = document.createElement('option');
      option.text = cur.fname;
      dropdown.add(option);
    });
  })();

  return {
    returnDomStrings: function() {
      return domStrings;
    }
  }

})();

const controlModule = (function(data, ui){

  const doms = ui.returnDomStrings();
  const setupEL = function() {
    document.querySelector(doms.dropdown).addEventListener('change',select)
  }

  const select =  function() {
    let x = document.querySelector(doms.dropdown);
    console.log(x.value);
  }

  return {
     init: function() {
      console.log('Application started');
      setupEL();
    }
  }

})(dataModule, uiModule);

controlModule.init()
```

I'm not so sure about the next part. Where do I even start? Please keep in mind that I'm just learning and that I'm not ready for Jquery yet. Keep any tips/answers to vanilla JS. I tried searching for solutions online, but I am not well versed enough in the terminology to know what to specifically search for.

Comment: It's not clear what you're stuck on, what the "next part" is, or what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Well I can chose the data and even fire an event on the change of the chosen data. I'm not sure how to go about displaying the data associated with that choice (in the console is fine). Eg: if I chose Justin, I'd like to display:

last name: Egan
age: 40
weight: 336
height: Tall

Comment: Does your change handler `const select =  function()` fire? Does it display what you expect in the console?

Comment: It does indeed. I built out the function to include a second ajax call and an if/then statement. is that right? I feel like making a call twice to the same site is bulky and unnecessary, but if it needs to be done...